# RMagick installation failed in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rmagick

I already installed the following:

- imagemagick
- libmagickwand-dev

but still i get this error.

```
======================================================================
Mon 05Oct09 19:36:06
This installation of RMagick 2.12.0 is configured for
Ruby 1.8.7 (i486-linux) and ImageMagick 6.4.5 Q16 
======================================================================



make
cc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fPIC  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp  -c rmmontage.c
cc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fPIC  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp  -c rmutil.c
cc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fPIC  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp  -c rmmain.c
cc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fPIC  -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp  -c rmimage.c
rmimage.c: In function ‘Image_function_channel’:
rmimage.c:5136: error: ‘MagickFunction’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rmimage.c:5136: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
rmimage.c:5136: error: for each function it appears in.)
rmimage.c:5136: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘function’
rmimage.c:5152: error: ‘function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rmimage.c:5158: error: ‘PolynomialFunction’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rmimage.c:5164: error: ‘SinusoidFunction’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [rmimage.o] Error 1
```

Comment: BTW, I installed the previous version (2.11.0) of RMagick and it worked. But still i want to know how can I fix this using RMagick 2.12.0.

Comment: `apt-get install imagemagick librmagick-ruby libmagickwand-dev` then `gem install rmagick -v '2.12.0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gem install rmagick -v '2.12.1'
```

for the version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.3.7 08/07/09 Q16
```

succeeded on Debian Lenny

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [2.12.1](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rmagick/) just got released, I just tested it on my ubuntu machine and it seems to install fine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try with ImageMagick  6.5.6 as that is the latest